# How to download csv file with QWebEngineView and QUrl

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I'm building a program which uses `QWebEngineView` and `QUrl` to display a website in my PyQt5 app (running on Windows 10).  However, I now want to be able to download a CSV file from the same website, but being a noob I can't seem to figure out how.

I'm familiar with using `requests`, `urllib.request`, `urllib3`, etc. for downloading files, but for this, I specifically want to do it with the QWebEngineView, as the user will have authenticated the request previously in the pyqt5 window.
The code to show the website in the first place goes like this:

```
self.view = QWebEngineView(self)
self.view.load(QUrl(url))
self.view.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
self.hbox.addWidget(self.view)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

Comment: you could provide the url, and if necessary the credentials. QWebEngineView is used as a browser, you just have to click on the file to download it

Comment: The website is [link](https://www.vendhq.com/) but I unfortunately can't provide the credentials.  There is no button to click, just a url created in my program which if I print it and copy & paste into chrome downloads the file if I am already on the same page as my program (interestingly it closes the tab as well, doesn't display anything).  I have tried just doing a `.load(QUrl(url))`, but it just doesn't do anything... I assume I need to somehow set a download directory?

Comment: okay, but when you get the url it is no longer necessary to be authenticated

Comment: I thought that originally, but if I try to run `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "test.csv")` it just crashes the program (although that code works fine with an image I tried).

Comment: Does the web page you indicate generate the download url or does your script do it?

Comment: My script does it, but I can print it out and copy into chrome which works fine, so I was assuming the issue wasn't there.

Comment: Ok, I'll understand, for the download you need to be logged in https://secure.vendhq.com ?, you could share a url of .csv

Comment: try my answer....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In QWebEngineView by default the downloads are not handled, to enable it you have to use the downloadRequested signal of QWebEngineProfile, this transports a QWebEngineDownloadItem that you have to accept if you want the download to start:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.view.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(
            self.on_downloadRequested
        )
        url = "https://domain/your.csv"
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWebEngineDownloadItem*")
    def on_downloadRequested(self, download):
        old_path = download.url().path()  # download.path()
        suffix = QtCore.QFileInfo(old_path).suffix()
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save File", old_path, "*." + suffix
        )
        if path:
            download.setPath(path)
            download.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to make a direct download you can use the download method of QWebEnginePage:

```py
self.view.page().download(QtCore.QUrl("https://domain/your.csv"))
```

**Update:**

```py
@QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWebEngineDownloadItem*")
def on_downloadRequested(self, download):
    old_path = download.url().path()  # download.path()
    suffix = QtCore.QFileInfo(old_path).suffix()
    path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
        self, "Save File", old_path, "*." + suffix
    )
    if path:
        download.setPath(path)
        download.accept()
        download.finished.connect(self.foo)

def foo(self):
    print("finished")
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, much appreciated.  For completeness could you include a function which triggers on download completion?

Comment: @codeacker use `download.finished.connect(foo_function)` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginedownloaditem.html#finished

Comment: I have added this directly after `download.accept()` which works perfectly and runs the function (just a print), but then the program immediately crashes and the file no longer downloads.  If I comment out that line, the file downloads but (obviously) doesn't run the function.  Do I have that line in the correct place?  Please excuse the noob questions!

Comment: @codeacker Without a [mcve] I could not tell you where the error is, I will only limit myself to showing an example in my update of my answer. If it does not work for you then you must provide the MCVE if you want help.

Comment: It appears we now have setDownloadDirectory() / setDownloadFileName() instead of setPath() for QWebEngineDownloadRequest class in Qt 6.2.

Comment: And also the signal for finished download appears to have changed: download.isFinishedChanged.connect(self.foo) https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginedownloadrequest.html#isFinished-prop